# Symfony2 form errors not showing, UniqueEntity error message not shown next to the corresponding field

Tags: php, symfony

I am having problems displaying form errors on registration page.

```
public function createAction {

    if ($request->isMethod("POST")) {

        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()){
           //do stuf
        }
        else{
           return array("form"=>$form->createView(), "companies"=> urlencode(json_encode($data)));
        }
    }
```

Now on my view I have :

```
{{ form_row(form.user.username) }}
{{ form_errors(form.user.username) }}
```

I am getting error if username is already in use. This is `var_dump` of

```
var_dump($form->getErrors());

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)#839 (4) {
    ["message":"Symfony\Component\Form\FormError":private]=>
    string(26) "Username is already in use"
    ["messageTemplate":protected]=>
    string(26) "Username is already in use"
    ["messageParameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["messagePluralization":protected]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

No errors are shown here: `{{ form_errors(form.user.username) }}`

In  my user entity I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"username"},
 *     message="Your E-Mail adress has already been registered"
 * )
 */

class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
```

I have also `'error_bubbling' => true` on all my inputs in for builder.

I have also try `$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate( $registration->getUser() );`
And then pass `'errors' => $errors` to view but message is not show at corresponding input.

Am I doing this wrong way?

**UPDATE**

When I put `{{ form_errors(form) }}` error message is shown.

Comment: Please post your full twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You turned on `error_bubbling` and therefore all error messages from child forms are bubbled up to root form.

If you want to show form errors for each field specifically, set it to `false`.

So to sum it up:

if `error_bubbling = true` then you show all errors like this:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

if `error_bubbling = false` then you show errors for each individual form separately:

```
{{ form_errors(form.user.username) }}
```

Comment: hvala Igore. Izgleda da je ovo bio problem.